# Is it possible for a variable inside an IF to project on a variable outside the IF?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote this script, which checks if a a certain file has been changed:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
if [ -z "$path" ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 [path (required)]" 1>&2
    exit 4
fi

lastmodsecs=`stat --format='%Y' $path`
lastmodsecshum=`date -d @$lastmodsecs`
basedate=$newdate
if [ $lastmodsecs != $basedate ]; then
        echo "CRITICAL: $path was last modified on $lastmodsecshum !"
        newdate=`stat --format='%Y' $path`
        exit 1
else
    echo "OK: $path hasn't been modified since $lastmodsecshum \(last supervized change\)"
    exit 0
fi
```

In case the `IF` statement is true I want to set the $newdate variable with the unix time of the last change and then project it to the $basedate variable which is just above the `IF`, is that possible?

Serge:
The script now looks like that, and the outcome is that if the file has been changed the status of the check stays on CRITICAL:/etc/passwd was last modified on `date` and for some reason the $persist file is not updated correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
if [ -z "$path" ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 [path (required)]" 1>&2
    exit 4
fi
lastmodsecs=`stat --format='%Y' $path`
lastmodsecshum=`date -d @$lastmodsecs`
persist="/usr/local/share/applications/file"
if [ -z $persist ]
        then newdate=`stat --format='%Y' $path`
else read newdate < $persist
fi
basedate=$newdate
if [ $lastmodsecs != $basedate ]; then
        echo "CRITICAL: $path was last modified on $lastmodsecshum !"
        echo $lastmodsecs > $persist
        exit 1
else
    echo "OK: $path hasn't been modified since $lastmodsecshum \(supervized change\)"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean with `project`, assign ?

Comment: Yes, it could be that I don't know the correct term... could be assign.

Comment: So what do you want to do with basedate after newdate is set ? You don't use basedate anymore in the script.

Comment: I think i got a little lost with myself there, my goal is to check if a file has been changed or not and if it has to display when.
But this is a Nagios check_command and I'm trying to prepare the command for the next run and thus the $basedate variable must contain the new last modify time... i'm pretty sure i'm not doing it properly...

Comment: "check if file has changed" ... changed since when? since last time you executed that script? since a specified time? Currently you seem to compare current file date with current file date. Probability is very high that those two dates are identical

Comment: I'm trying to check if the file has been changed since the last check

Comment: if your goal ist not educational, and if using bash means that you're running Linux, consider to reap the benefits of a linux filesystem hook called imodify - you can use it to execute a command or script when specific file events, on specified files, are taking place. For example, by setting a mark that change occured, the moment it happens.

Comment: "changed since the last check" - then you need to know when you last checked.

Comment: The script does the check, so I wanted the script to update the last modification time to an external file and then check against it

Comment: And my goal is not educational, I'm trying to build a nagios check that will monitor file change to /etc/passwd and raise an alert. I'll check imodify, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the script has permissions to write on $persist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is expected to be run in a loop with `newdate` being initially the value from last run. Normally this could work fine if the loop was in the script :

```
...
# newdate first initialisation
newdate=`stat --format='%Y' $path`
while true
    do lastmodsecs=`stat --format='%Y' $path`
    lastmodsecshum=`date -d @$lastmodsecs`
    basedate=$newdate
    if [ $lastmodsecs != $basedate ]; then
            echo "CRITICAL: $path was last modified on $lastmodsecshum !"
            newdate=$lastmodsecs
            exit 1
    else
        echo "OK: $path hasn't been modified since $lastmodsecshum \(last supervized change\)"
    fi
done
```

But as I saw your `exit 0` and `exit 1` this script is also intended to return a status to a caller. You cannot use environment because a program is not allowed to modify its parent environment. So the only possibility is to have newdate managed by caller, or persisted to a file. This last is easy and needs no modification in caller :

```
...
persist=/path/to/private/persist/file
# eventual first time initialization or get newdat from $persist
if [ -z $persist ]
then newdate=`stat --format='%Y' $path`
else read newdate < $persist
fi
...
basedate=$newdate
if [ $lastmodsecs != $basedate ]; then
        echo "CRITICAL: $path was last modified on $lastmodsecshum !"
        echo $lastmodsecs > $persist
        exit 1
else
    echo "OK: $path hasn't been modified since $lastmodsecshum \(last supervized change\)"
    exit 0
fi
```

Of course the tests are yours as you are speaking of Nagios ...

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question with the outcome of the script.

Answer (score 0):

For checking whether file date is more recent than the time of last check, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
lastchecked="/tmp/lastchecked.state"       
file="/my/file"

# compare file date against date of last check 
[[ "$file" -nt "$lastchecked" ]] && echo "$file has been modified since last check"

# remember time when this check was done
touch "$lastchecked"
```